# IIS URL Rewrite pass query parameter without including it in the URL

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have a URL similar to `example.com/navbar?tab=1` or `example.com/navbar?tab=2` I want to be able to *rewrite* the URL to a standalone [slug](https://www.semrush.com/blog/what-is-a-url-slug/) URL. I'd like `example.com/navbar?tab=1` to rewrite to `example.com/this-is-my-slug` and `example.com/navbar?tab=2` to rewrite to `example.com/another-slug-of-mine` I'd like these URLs rewritten instead of redirected so the user doesn't have to see the query parameters. But I'd also like for the two pages not to be mixed so that I'm not allowed to go to `example.com/this-is-my-slug?tab=2` and end up viewing `example.com/another-slug-of-mine` I tried using rewrite maps, various different patterns, but this is what I have now in my `Web.config`.

```
...
<rule name="NavigationRewrite1">
    <match url="^this-is-my-slug" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/navbar?tab=1" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="NavigationRewrite2">
    <match url="^another-slug-of-mine" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/navbar?tab=2" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
...
```

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do using IIS Rewrite rules? Or would I have to look into routing from C#?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite `example.com/navbar?tab=1` as `example.com/this-is-my-slug`, you can refer to this rule:

```
<rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^navbar$" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="tab=1" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="example.com/this-is-my-slug" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```